# How to make .toggle from .animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, toggle

I have hamburger menu that comes in with an animation. When I  click again on hamburger menu (after I have already escaped from the menu), the menu appears without animation.

I assume it is caused by .animate - I need to make .toggle

> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {
>   $("#openMenu").click(function() {
>     $("#main").toggle(200);
>     $("#menuSection").toggle(200);
>     $(".menu").animate({ left: "2%" });
>   });
> });
> ```

CSS:

> ```
> .menu {  
> height: 100px;   
> width: 0px;  
> background-color: #450a5a;  
> display: flex;   
> position: absolute;   
> left: -50%;   
> cursor: pointer; 
> pointer-events: none;   
> transition: all 0.5s; 
> }
> ```

Comment: How do you escape from your menu?

Comment: I am using **.toggle** to escape from menu. @AliElKhateeb

Comment: please show us the code so we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you click again on the `#openMenu` element to trigger menu closing animation when it's opened. Calling `.animate` that you have in your code again, after .menu element's style it already set to `left: 2%;` will not change anything. You have to implement code that will trigger either "out" animation or "in" animation depending on whether or not the menu is opened.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#openMenu").click(function() {
        $("#main").toggle(200);
        $("#menuSection").toggle(200);
        var menu = $(".menu");
        if (menu.css("left") == "2%") { //if the "in" animation was already performed
            menu.animate({ left: "0%" }); //revert back to normal
        } else {
            menu.animate({ left: "2%" }); //perform "in" animation
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but this is not working. For first time there is an animation. But if I try to click again on the menu there is no animation.

Comment: @PohodePES You have mentioned that you use .toggle to close the menu. Which elements are you calling .toggle on? In order for the code above to work, function that handles click event has to be called both on opening and closing of the menu.